# bs4 soup.select() vs. soup.find()

Tags: python, html, python-3.x, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am trying to scrape the text of some elements in a table using `requests` and `BeautifulSoup`, specifically the country names and the 2-letter country codes from [this website](https://country-code.cl/).

Here is my code, which I have progressively walked back:

```
import requests
import bs4

res = requests.get('https://country-code.cl/')
res.raise_for_status()
soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(res.text)

for i in range(3):
    row = soup.find(f'#row{i} td')
    print(row) # printing to check progress for now
```

I had hoped to go row-by-row and walk the tags to get the strings like so (over range 249). However, `soup.find()` doesn't appear to work, just prints blank lists. `soup.select()` however, works fine:

```
for i in range(3):
    row = soup.select(f'#row{i} td')
    print(row)
```

Why does `soup.find()` not work as expected here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While `.find()` deals only with the first occurence of an element, `.select()` / `.find_all()` will give you a `ResultSet` you can iterate.

There are a lot of ways to get your goal, but basic pattern is mostly the same - select rows of the table and iterate over them.

In this first case I selected table by its `id` and close to your initial approach the `<tr>` also by its `id` while using `css selector` and the `[id^="row"]` that represents id attribute whose value starts with `row`. In addition I used `.stripped_strings` to extract the text from the elements, stored it in a list and pick it by index :

```
for row in soup.select('#countriesTable tr[id^="row"]'):
    row = list(row.stripped_strings)
    print(row[2], row[3])
```

or more precisely selecting all `<tr>` in `<tbody>` of tag with id `countriesTable`:

```
for row in soup.select('#countriesTable tbody tr'):
    row = list(row.stripped_strings)
    print(row[2], row[3])
```

...

---

An alternative and in my opinion best way to scrape tables is the use of `pandas.read_html()` that works with `beautifulsoup` under the hood and is doing most work for you:

```
import pandas as pd
pd.read_html('https://country-code.cl/', attrs={'id':'countriesTable'})[0].dropna(axis=1, how='all').iloc[:-1,:]
```

or to get only the two specific rows:

```
pd.read_html('https://country-code.cl/', attrs={'id':'countriesTable'})[0].dropna(axis=1, how='all').iloc[:-1,[1,2]]
```

|  | Name | ISO 2 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | Afghanistan | AF |
| 1 | Åland Islands | AX |
| 2 | Albania | AL |
| 3 | Algeria | DZ |
| 4 | American Samoa | AS |
| 5 | Andorra | AD |

...

Comment: I like how clear this first solution appears to be. Could you explain the `tr[id^="row"]`? specifically I have not seen `^`

Comment: `tr[id^="row"]` represents the id attribute of the `<tr>` whose value starts with `row`

Comment: Thank you so much. I have to say I am quite partial to the "readability"

Answer (score 1):

`find` expects the first argument to be the DOM element you're searching, it won't work with CSS selectors.

So you'll need:

```
row = soup.find('tr', { 'id': f"row{i}" })
```

To get the `tr` with the desired ID.

---

Then to get the 2-letter country code, for the first `a` with `title: ISO 3166-1 alpha-2 code` and get it's `.text`:

```py
iso = row.find('a', { 'title': 'ISO 3166-1 alpha-2 code' }).text
```

---

To get the full name, there is no classname to search for, so I'd use take the second element, then we'll need to search for the `span` containing the country name:

```py
name = row.findAll('td')[2].findAll('span')[2].text
```

---

Putting it all together gives:

```py
import requests
import bs4

res = requests.get('https://country-code.cl/')
res.raise_for_status()
soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(res.text, 'html.parser')

for i in range(3):
    row = soup.find('tr', { 'id': f"row{i}" })

    iso = row.find('a', { 'title': 'ISO 3166-1 alpha-2 code' }).text
    name = row.findAll('td')[2].findAll('span')[2].text

    print(name, iso)
```

Which outputs:

```
Afghanistan  AF
Åland Islands  AX
Albania  AL
```

Comment: Awesome. This is just what I needed. I didn't quite understand the difference in walking the tags with DOM vs. CSS selector

Answer (score 1):

`find_all() and select()` select  a list but `find() and select_one()` select only single element.

```
import requests
import bs4
import pandas as pd

res = requests.get('https://country-code.cl/')
res.raise_for_status()
soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(res.text,'lxml')

data=[]
for row in soup.select('.tablesorter.mark > tbody tr'):
    name=row.find("span",class_="sortkey").text
    country_code=row.select_one('td:nth-child(4)').text.replace('\n','').strip()

    data.append({
        'name':name,
        'country_code':country_code})

df= pd.DataFrame(data)
print(df)
```

**Output:**

```
                 name    country_code
0          afghanistan           AF
1        aland-islands           AX
2              albania           AL
3              algeria           DZ
4       american-samoa           AS
..                 ...          ...
244  wallis-and-futuna           WF
245     western-sahara           EH
246              yemen           YE
247             zambia           ZM
248           zimbabwe           ZW

[249 rows x 2 columns]
```

Comment: I really like this solution since it allows easy pulling from the df. How did you determine the tags to look for?

Comment: On second look, it looks like `country_code` pulls the continent code instead of the ISO code - but would selecting the ISO code just be a matter of a different `td:nth-child`?

Comment: @chemicalwill, Thanks.  The html DOM and desired data selection will say in which way , you have to select tags with bs4 locator strategy or you have to use css selector  or you can use one of them or both. Please you can take help from here:https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/